# Как быть с устойчивыми выражениями, если они не сочетаются по времени с основной мыслью?

Tags: грамотная-речь, идиомы

Например выражение ***ни в какие ворота не лезет***. Далее, я хочу сказать: *Если они и завтра квас не разольют, то это... (ни в какие ворота уже не... **по**лезет (?)).* Но можно ли так искажать фразу, добавляя приставку? Я думаю, что нельзя. Тогда остаётся лишь искать замену этому выражению, чаще всего меняя на обычное (не идиоматическое)? Говорю *чаще всего*, потому что имею в виду не только этот случай, но и другие подобные.

Comment: Может быть, надо так построить предложение, чтобы не менять оборот, например: Если они и завтра квас не разольют, то ... (а это уже ни в какие ворота  не лезет).

Comment: Верно, тоже вариант! Другое дело, такой у меня оттенок мысли в конкретный момент или нет, но может оказаться и таким. :)

Answer (score 2):

В Нацкорпусе можно найти много примеров употребления прошедшего времени.

> Это ни в какие ворота не лезло. [Евгений Евтушенко. «Волчий паспорт» (1999)]

Но нет ни одного примера с будущим временем. Очевидно, так сложилось. Думаю, в таком случае нужно обходиться без этого выражения.

Вариант типа "Если они и завтра квас не разольют, то будет скандал (а это уже ни в какие ворота не лезет)" допустим, но тут другая семантика. Сначала описывается то, что будет, а потом дается оценка безотносительно времени события (скандал - это то, что ни в какие ворота не лезет).

Comment: Мне кажется, что этот фразеологизм является фразеологическим единством. В таких оборотах  форма и вид глаголов может меняться, но  реально какой-либо вариант имеет наибольшую частотность. Из примеров: не лезет (основной вариант), также: не лезло (несколько примеров), не пролезет, не лезущий (единичные примеры). Вариативность фразеологизмов https://megapredmet.ru/1-78936.html Примеры предложений  https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/ни%20в%20какие%20ворота%20не%20лезет

Comment: Спасибо большое, М_Г и Ксения!

Comment: @Ксения и М_Г, вспомнил, что изначально я задумался, можно ли сказать "это будет куда ни шло". Как вы считаете? Если кто ещё прочитает, то конечно буду тоже рад ответу.